# Trying to get a dynamic order by clause in Linq to Entities

Tags: vb.net, linq, frameworks, entity

I am trying to get a dynamic order by clause working but can't figure out the syntax. Thought I'd cracked it with inline if statements but these aren't supported in EF.

The user will be able to select a field to sort on (initially ascending) probably by clicking on the dgv header.

This is my code: -

```
Dim q = (From customer In db.tblcustomers.Where(Function(x) CBool(x.f_rn >= 0 And x.cu_brn = "00" _
    And (txtFiltAccno.Text.Trim = "" Or x.cu_accno.ToUpper.Contains(txtFiltAccno.Text.ToUpper.Trim)) _
    And (txtFiltCustName.Text.Trim = "" Or       x.cu_name.ToUpper.Contains(txtFiltCustName.Text.ToUpper.Trim)) _
    And (txtFiltPhone.Text.Trim = "" Or x.cu_telno.ToUpper.Contains(txtFiltPhone.Text.ToUpper.Trim)) _
    And (txtFiltFax.Text.Trim = "" Or x.cu_faxno.ToUpper.Contains(txtFiltFax.Text.ToUpper.Trim)) _
    And (txtFiltEmail.Text.Trim = "" Or x.cu_email.ToUpper.Contains(txtFiltEmail.Text.ToUpper.Trim))))
    select customer.f_rn, customer.cu_accno, customer.cu_name, customer.cu_add1, customer.cu_add2,     customer.cu_add3, customer.cu_add4, customer.cu_add5,
            customer.cu_telno, customer.cu_faxno, customer.cu_email).OrderBy(Function(u) 
IIf(a = "cu_name", u.cu_name,
IIf(a = "cu_add1", u.cu_add1,
IIf(a = "cu_add2", u.cu_add2,
IIf(a = "cu_add3", u.cu_add3,
IIf(a = "cu_add4", u.cu_add4,
IIf(a = "cu_add5", u.cu_add5,
IIf(a = "cu_telno", u.cu_telno,
IIf(a = "cu_faxno", u.cu_faxno,
IIf(a = "cu_email", u.cu_email, u.cu_accno)))))))))).Skip((pagenum - 1) * 25).Take(25)
```

Comment: Thanks but the user may want to search based on more than one condition e.g. Show me all the blue widgets ordered between two dates and despatched to a specific area.

Comment: Also I am limiting the query to 25 records so sorting on the dgv will only sort those 25 records not the whole table. As far as I can see it has to be a trip back to the db especially as the new records may have been added in the meantime

Comment: Apologies,I've just reread your message and am just breaking the query down but going to run analyser on the query to see what it is doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ooof. That might well turn out some nasty, and likely slow performing SQL. Take a read of https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/smart-logic (not the blog I wanted to link to - but I can't find the one I'm thinking of, that was a lot more old school looking, like it was once a usenet post)

Queries in LINQ are cumulative, and they only run when something happens to enumerate the result, like calling ToArray on it, or `ForEach`ing it. This means you can build your query dynamically in several steps. (I've dumbed things down a bit for clarity/to illustrate a point here; i haven't used your actual column names):

```
Dim q as IEnumerable(Of Customer) = db.Customers

If nameTextBox.Text <> "" Then q = q.Where(Function(x) x.Name = nameTextBox.Text)

If ageTextBox.Text <> "" Then q = q.Where(Function(x) x.Age = ageTextBox.Text)

If jobTextBox.Text <> "" Then q = q.Where(Function(x) x.Age = jobTextBox.Text)

If sortByCombo.SelectedValue = "Name" Then q = q.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Name)
Else If ....
```

If you only put something in the `Name` box, the `q` has one `Where` called on it. If you put something in all 3 boxes, the `Where` are cumulative and will act as one with terms ANDed in the SQL. The db query is not run at any point in the above, even if you add the OrderBy. If you want more info on this look up "LINQ deferred execution". At the moment you try to read the result, the query will be run.

ps; I'm not sure I'd have the DB do the ordering, necessitating a re-query every time the order is changed - perhaps just load the results into a control that knows how to sort (most grid controls, windows and web, know how to cache and sort their data to avoid a round trip to somewhere that provides the data), or use a client side container that can handle the sorting, like e.g. a DataTable, SortedList etc